# How to Set Up Application Insights from an ARM Template

Tags: azure, web-applications

I'm trying to set up an App Service, an App Service Plan, and App Insights via an Azure DevOps release pipeline.

I'm creating the three resources successfully with resource group templates, but I can't work out how to install App Insights properly.

If I go to the App Service in the Azure Portal, I get the following message:

> Enable Application Insights through site extension without redeploying your code.
>
> There is an update available for Application Insights site extension that provides a better experience.

I've tried adding an "Azure App Service Manage" step to my release pipeline, set to install the "Application Insights extension for Azure App Service" extension.

[Screenshot of Release Pipeline Step for Installing AppInsights Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIkXR.png)

In addition, I've added an "Azure App Service Manage" step to my release pipeline, set to "Enable Continuous Monitoring".

[Screenshot of Release Pipeline Step for Enabling Continuous Monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlJUC.png)

But the result is still that AppInsights is connected, but the extension is not installed:

[Screenshot of Azure Portal showing extension is not turned on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E01UH.png)